# inconsistent sort behavior

Tags: unix, text, sorting, ascii, gnu

I have a sample file containg "aA0_- " characters on each one on a single. Sorting it using GNU sort gives the following sort order:

```
$ cat /tmp/sample | sort

_
-
0
a
A
```

after appending some other character, we obtain a different order (non-alphanumeric characters seems to have lower priority):

```
$ cat /tmp/sample | sed 's/$/x/' | sort
0x
ax
Ax
 x
_x
-x
```

while when we insert this character to the beginning, we obtain the original sort order:

```
$ cat /tmp/sample | sed 's/^/x/' | sort
x 
x_
x-
x0
xa
xA
```

.. what is the explanation of such behavior?

**UPDATE**

when '`z`' and '`Z`' characters are included in the sample, the result seems yet sranger:

```
$ cat /tmp/sample | sed 's/$/x/' | sort
0x
ax
Ax
 x
_x
-x
zx
Zx
```

.. but in the light of the correct answer, it is so because all '', '`_`' and '`-`' are whitespace in the current locale (en_US.UTF-8) and are not ignored in sorting.

Comment: @[Sanjay Manohar] locale is en_US.UTF-8. hmm, good hint ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your locale file should contain a definition of LC_COLLATE.
This determines the sort order of characters.
Also check the definition of LC_CTYPE,  and which characters are classified as 'space'.

if '-' and '_' are classified as space, you might find the results you have shown.